# Getting a range of lines between timestamps from /var/log/messages

Tags: bash, sed, grep, date

I want to get all lines between two timestamps from /var/log/messages.
I only have start time which I provide to my script as input.
The script then should get me all the lines till next day as output.
I tried this-

```
startDate=$1
toDate=`date -d "${startDate}+1day"`
sed -n '/${startDate}/ , /${toDate}/p' messages*
```

However I found a problem with this approach when the `$toDate` pattern is not found in message logs. So I modified my code to this-

```
startDate=$1
toDate=`date -d "${startDate}+1day"`
until [ `grep -Fxq ${toDate} messages*` ];
do
    echo ${toDate}
    epoch=`date -d "${toDate}" +%s`
    new_epoch=$(($epoch+1))
    next_ts=`date -d "1970-01-01 ${new_epoch} sec"`
    toDate=${next_ts:4:15}
done
sed -n '/${startDate}/ , /${toDate}/p' messages*
```

Now I'm having a hard time matching date in the logs.
For my input of `Nov  6 07:17:04 UTC 2017`, code generates next date as `Nov 7 07:17:04`. Notice that actual timestamps in message logs contains two spaces between month name and single digit dates. So I'm not not able to match the string.

Is there anyway around this?
I want the script to work with double-digit dates(like 10) as well.

Comment: I never even knew `until` was a thing in bash. I am fairly certain though, that `date` has a man page which covers the topic `FORMAT`.

Comment: I would go for an awk on the form of `awk '/initial date/,/final date/'`. See [How to filter logs easily with awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34311140/1983854)

Comment: How about `date +%a\ \ %d\ %T\ %Z` (or the same thing quoted without the backslashes, which unfortunately is not displayed properly in a comment)?

Comment: If this a system running systemd, you can use journalctl --since and --until.

Comment: @fedorqui Even with awk I see the same problem. If the final date is not found in logs, it print lines which which are not between range of timestamps too.

Comment: Not really: if the timestamp can be sorted alphabetically, anything after *final_date* won't be printed.

Comment: @pragmatic is right, if _final_date_ doesn't exist in the log but there are log entries dated after that, those later entries are printed. `grep` for the desired date first and pipe that to `awk` as described and you should get the results you want.